# Why can't i import ciphersweet StringProvider

Tags: php, encryption

I installed ciphersweet on my server using composer but when i try to import the library i'm getting this error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider' not found in index.php.
```

Seems like the dependency didn't install correcty, i'm lost can you help please.

It's a php error.

here's my code :

```
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\EncryptedRow;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\AlphaCharactersOnly;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\FirstCharacter;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Transformation\Lowercase;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\Backend\FIPSCrypto;
use ParagonIE\CipherSweet\KeyProvider\StringProvider;


$provider = new StringProvider('a981d3894b5884f6965baea64a09bb5b4b59c10e857008fc814923cf2f2de558');
$engine = new CipherSweet($provider, new FIPSCrypto());



/** @var CipherSweet $engine */
$row = (new EncryptedRow($engine, 'contacts'))
    ->addTextField('first_name')
    ->addTextField('last_name')
    ->addFloatField('latitude')
    ->addFloatField('longitude');

// Notice the ->addRowTransform() method:
$row->addCompoundIndex(
    $row->createCompoundIndex(
        'contact_first_init_last_name',
        ['first_name', 'last_name'],
        64, // 64 bits = 8 bytes
        true
    )
        ->addTransform('first_name', new AlphaCharactersOnly())
        ->addTransform('first_name', new Lowercase())
        ->addTransform('first_name', new FirstCharacter())
        ->addTransform('last_name', new AlphaCharactersOnly())
        ->addTransform('last_name', new Lowercase())
);

$prepared = $row->prepareRowForStorage([
    'first_name' => 'Jane',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
    'latitude' => 52.52,
    'longitude' => -33.106,
    'extraneous' => true
]);

var_dump($prepared);
?>
```

Comment: Have you load the `vendor/autoload.php` files?
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Comment: No i didn't , what shoud be the __DIR__ ?

Comment: `__DIR__` is a magic PHP constant (see https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)
It returns the directory that this file is in.

Comment: i'm getting this : failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: index.php is not in the root folder maybe that's the reason

Comment: In that case, you need to add .. to the path

Comment: I gave it a relative path and now it's working. thank you :) . require_once  '../../../../vendor/autoload.php';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the `vendor/autoload.php` in order for the installed packages to work.

For example, add `require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';` to the top of your file.
This will make php aware of the namespaces in your packages.

You might need to change this if your files are not in the root directory of your application. For example, if your files are in `app/` directory, those files need to use `require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php'`

See https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading for more details.

Comment: i'm getting this : Warning: require_once(/home/u337257260/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wallet../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/u337257260/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wallet/index.php on line 2

Comment: Oops, I miss the leading /

Comment: im getting this : Warning: require_once(/home/u31037257260/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wallet/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory. maybe the dependency didn't install correcty

Comment: Could you give me a result from `echo(__DIR__);` in your index file? And also the path `vendor/autoload.php`

Comment: here's the result : /home/u37857260/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/wallet

Comment: I gave it a relative path and now it's working. thank you :) . require_once  '../../../../vendor/autoload.php';